# Exporting custom configurations from Drupal

Tags: importing-exporting, configuration

After installing a Drupal7 site, I have made several configurations/customizations over time. Now I would like to export them somehow, in order to load them to another site. But the problem is that I don't remember exactly what I have done. The Features module does not help because you have to tell it exactly what to export, but I don't remember all the changes.

I know that this is a difficult problem on Drupal7, which is expected to be solved on Drupal8. But I am asking just in case that somebody knows any tricks that can help to solve it on Drupal7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Configuration Management](http://drupal.org/project/configuration) module.

> The configuration management module enables the ability to keep track
>   of specific configurations on a Drupal site, provides the ability to
>   move these configurations between different environments (local, dev,
>   qa, prod), and also move configurations between completely different
>   sites (migrate configurations) without the use of modules with all
>   configuration being owned by the site.

It's kind of a backport of features worked towards in the Drupal 8 [Config Management Initiative](http://groups.drupal.org/build-systems-change-management/cmi).  You basically trac certain elements of configuration on your site (this bit is *relatively* similar to Features), and then it tells you when there are differences between what is stored in the filesystem and what is stored in the database (referred to as ActiveStore and DataStore). These config files can then be versioned and deployed.

As an added bonus, of you install the [Diff](http://drupal.org/project/diff) module you can see what's actually been changed with regards to ActiveStore vs DataStore :-)

***tl;dr***

The [Configuration Management](http://drupal.org/project/configuration) module attempts to bring Drupal 8 style configuration management to Drupal 7.

Comment: This module seems certainly useful, and better than Features (for my case). But, is it possible to compare (diff) 2 configurations from different sites? From the drush commands available, I think that there isn't any straight-forward way to do it.

Comment: This module helped me to solve my problem, although the solution was not 100% automatic and required some manual work. I have described in this blog how I did it:  http://dashohoxha.blogspot.com/2013/03/exporting-custom-configurations-from-a-drupal-7-site.html

Answer (score 2):

You can [features module](http://drupal.org/project/features). So you can create a feature of several configuration and can use in other installation.

**Sorry I missed the features part in question, which you already know.**

*I think features is the best solution for exporting configurations. other than features nothing is there for exporting all configurations without telling what to export.*

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [features_orphan](https://drupal.org/project/features_orphans) module.  AFAIK it still only works with features 7.x-1.x, not 2.x.

This will show you all of the config which doesn't currently live in features.  Combine this with the "drush fd [feature-name]" you should be able to see all of your changes.

One thing to keep in mind is that it is very rare that you will want to export **all** of the config from one site and use it on another.  There are some variables such as site_key, cron_* etc which you won't want in the export.

Comment: I think that features_orphans, from its description is the equivalent of: `drush features-components --not-exported '%:%'` but has a GUI for it. Anyway, it does not show me what I have changed since the initial installation.

Comment: @dashohoxha Unless you took a snapshot of *exactly* what was there before you made your changes, there is no magic solution to track your changes. Even then you're looking at *diff*ing the entire thing. I'm afraid there is no magic bullet for your issue :(

Comment: @Chapabu I can take a snapshot of a freshly installed Drupal and compare it to the snapshot of the current system. But the problem is that this diff is not so clean/meaningful/useful.

Comment: @dashohoxha If you're looking to deploy a site configuration (which it sounds like you are), then I'd check my answer below.  Configuration Management is much most useful than Features for your use case :)

Comment: @Chapabu I will check it for sure. Thanks for suggesting it.